# TRON url issue swift

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift

I'm using TRON framework for swift and I'm getting an error due to my url.
This is the code:

```
let relatedTronUrl = TRON(baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org")

func fetchRelatedFeed(id: Int, completion: @escaping () -> ()){
    let request: APIRequest<Related, JSONError> = relatedTronUrl.request("/3/tv/1402/similar?api_key=myAPIkey&language=en-US&page=1")

    request.perform(withSuccess: { (related) in
        print("Successfully fatched our json objects")
        completion()
    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch json ",err)
    }
}
```

As you can see the correct url should be: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/1402/similar?api_key=myAPIkey&language=en-US&page=1`
but when I run my application I get a JSON error:

```
Failed to fetch json  APIError<JSONError>(request: Optional(https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/1402/similar%3Fapi_key=myAPIkey&language=en-US&page=1), response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x610000235f20> { URL: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/1402/similar%3Fapi_key=myAPIkey&language=en-US&page=1 } { status code: 401, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 86;
"Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 01 Mar 2017 16:58:38 GMT";
Server = openresty;
Status = "401 Unauthorized";
"X-RateLimit-Limit" = 40;
"X-RateLimit-Remaining" = 39;
"X-RateLimit-Reset" = 1488387528;} }), data: Optional(86 bytes), error: Optional(Alamofire.AFError.responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(401))), errorModel: Optional(BookFinde.RelatedService.JSONError))
```

I think the problem is due to TRON's request because the correct url is: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/1402/similar?api_key=myAPIkey&language=en-US&page=1`

But what I get is: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/1402/similar%3Fapi_key=myAPIkey&language=en-US&page=1`

As you can see the difference is `?` transformed to `%3F`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TRON is apparently expecting the request parameter to be a `path` and you're trying to include `query` parameters.  Check the `APIRequest` class and see if it allows you to specify query parameters, and then split your call up into creating the request with only the path portion and then adding the query portion.

Comment: @DavidBerry Thank you, I had to add the queries by adding parameters.

Comment: You might post your actual solution as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
let relatedTronUrl = TRON(baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org")

func fetchRelatedFeed(id: Int, completion: @escaping () -> ()){
    let request: APIRequest<Related, JSONError> = relatedTronUrl.request("3/tv/\(id)/similar")

    // I had to manually add the paramaters in this way
    request.parameters = ["api_key":"myAPIkey","language":"en-US","page":"1"]

    request.perform(withSuccess: { (related) in
        print("Successfully fatched our json objects")
        completion()
    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch json ",err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to add the method too? like    request.method = .get

Comment: I can accept my answer tomorrow. @MatGrlt It works without add the method .get